# How to make height inversely proportional to width?

Tags: html, css

I'm using divs that have text in them, and I want to make it so that when the width of the window gets smaller, the height gets bigger so that it can still contain the div. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You question is not clear, but you might be looking for `min-height`.

Comment: This should be the default response. Without a demo of your code it's hard to comment further.

Comment: Isn't this automatic behaviour? Div element will automatically take up specified X% of width (assuming it's relative, otherwise it doesn't make sense). When window is resized, the said element's width will get smaller or bigger and your element will grow in height to compensate and fit the content, which is only the case for non-fixed height, as @arniekoz suggested, you should use `min-height`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got your point. Try this-

```css
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
 
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
 
.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="clearfix">
  <p>Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta. Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Proin eget tortor risus. 
  </p>
</div>
```